# Is there any memory leak in this Stack Implementation?

Tags: java, data-structures, memory-leaks

In the below stack implementation, which uses a simple linked object and doesn't use any collection. Do you see any memory leak?

Below Code:

```
public class Stack {

    private Node nextNode = null;

    private class Node {
        String data;
        Node adjNode;
    }

    public void put(String data) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = data;
        node.adjNode = this.nextNode;
        this.nextNode = node;
    }

    public String pop() {
        String data = nextNode.data;
        this.nextNode = nextNode.adjNode;
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stack myStack = new Stack();
        myStack.put("SP");
        myStack.put("Senthil");
        myStack.put("Arumugam");

        System.out.println("myStack.pop():" + myStack.pop());
        System.out.println("myStack.pop():" + myStack.pop());
        System.out.println("myStack.pop():" + myStack.pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably synchronize that but if you're calling that from only one thread I don't see where a leak could occur.

Comment: @Hichamov a double linked list used as a stack (very inefficient of course but it probably doesn't matter).

Comment: Yeah I understood and deleted the comment ... sorry

Comment: I agree with @dystroy

Comment: @dystroy Sure, this stack is like all basic collections not threadsafe, but how does that relate to leaks? Sharing a `Stack` between threads may leak the entire stack if you leak the thread but that's not the fault of the stack

Comment: @zapl it looks like you could get a cyclic reference (and then an endless stack) if you do a put and a pop at the same time. Might be considered as a kind of leak. I agree this isn't really a "leak" bug but a synchronization bug (that's one of the reasons I made my answer reputation-less).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have a memory leak in java in this type of program since dangling pointers are cleaned by the garbage collector.

Comment: You can approximate a leak by, eg, creating an ever growing linked list of "old" links that will never be referenced or reused.

Comment: Of course memory leaks are common in Java as in all other languages, even if java makes it impossible to have some *kinds* of memory leaks you have in languages without managed memory.

Comment: I have clarified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This program doesn't exhibit any kind of memory leak, assuming you don't share an instance between threads.

If you want to access that code from different threads, synchronize the `put` and `pop` methods.